# Why do guards show up when I steal things from an empty house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm in a room of a house and I steal stuff. The only other person in the room is my follower, so I think no one will find out. However, a guard shows up.

Why?

For example, in the House of Grey Mane:

No one else is there when I steal things, except my follower, but a guard shows up anyways.

Comment: Jim I haven't a clue what you're actually asking. The progression of what's going on is unreadable.

Comment: This should be several questions. But I think it's nice to have this in one place. How can I steal and get away with it? If I am alone in a room, can I steal everything? Or is there an omnipotent cctv in every room that will notify guard that I have stolen stuffs?

Comment: @JimThio firstly, if you have "several questions", that automatically flags it as "Too Broad". We try to aim for a "One question, One answer" system. In which case I would say that you can break this into two questions: "How can I steal stuff without being caught?", and "I've been arrested and gone to jail. What now?"

Comment: @JimThio Did you see a notification about a bounty being added while you were stealing the items? If not, it's possible that you had a bounty from a previously-committed crime, and the guards only just caught up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Some followers will still put a bounty on your head if you steal or trespass. And if the guard comes In, that means there already chasing you. Followers can't call guards but can still put bounties on your head. The only other way they could come in, is if someone saw you pick the lock to break in, therefore they will call guards. Oh, and if someone sees you trespass and is not your friend, They will call the guards, Regardless if you leave or not.